# Usage of SED for text replacing

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, grep

I need to replace a pattern containing string like `?:` , `?'` , `??` and `?+` within a line of text.

If it `?:` then it should be `:` , `?'` then `'` , `??` then `?` and `?+` then `+` .
I tried
`sed -i 's/\?:/:/g'` ,
`sed -i "s/\?'/'/g"` ,
`sed -i 's/\??/?/g'` and
`sed -i 's/\?+/+/g'`.

While `'s/\?:/:/g'` and `sed -i "s/\?'/'/g"` worked fine but I am facing some issues while using `sed -i 's/\??/?/g'` and `sed -i 's/\?+/+/g'`.
**The pattern are not getting replaced correctly.**
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: it's incredibly hard to read which characters of your post are intended to be punctuation, as opposed to characters in the string. please use StackOverflow's inline code formatting; surround your strings and patterns with `

Comment: Hi...I have edited the question a bit and made it some readable. I hope it is more clear.

Comment: Hope I have done it now as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using perl, you could do:

```
perl -api -e  "s/\?(?=[:'?+])//g" file.txt
```

This will remove every question mark `?` that is followed by any of `:`, `'`, `?` or `+`

Comment: Thanks so much. It works but it prints the change in terminal but I want to edit the file inline i.e to change the original file. Could you please help in doing that?

Comment: Thank you so much..@Toto

Answer (score 0):

With sed :

```
sed -i -r "s/\?([\?:\+'])/\1/g" input_file.txt
```

It modifies `input_file.txt` in place (`-i`) and used extended regular expressions (`-r`), so `?` and `+` need to be escaped.

If the pattern is found, it replaces the whole pattern with the second character.

Comment: I have tried with a sample I/P.I/P - `?+?+?+?:?:?:?:???????'?'?'?'`.The O/P should be `+++::::''''` but I am getting `+++::::???''''`.Means SED is only doing the replacement one time i.e if it's `??????` then SED gives `???`,but it should be only `?`.Please help.